# Multiple submit buttons in Razor view form

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a razor view with a BeginForm command and a loop within that in which I create a html table with a submit button in each row.  My question is when I submit the form for a particular row back to the controller how do I ensure that I know which row that button relates to?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's in my mind is to set a hidden input before submitting the form by a javascript function.

If you use jquery it can be sth like this:

```
$("input:submit").click(function() {
   $("hiddenInput").val(
       $(this).closest("input[name*='yourPrimaryKey']").val()
   );
});
```

it finds the value of an input containing the ID of a row which its button was clicked.

Answer (score 3):

In your loop, just give a name (for example submittedButton) to your submit button and set it's value to the row identification.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach(var row in myRows)
    {
        <input type="submit" name="submittedButton" value="@row.ID" />
    }
}
```

In your controller define a string argument which it's name is the same as submit button's name (in this example submittedButton) like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourController(string submittedButton)
{
   // submittedButton contains ID of selected row
   return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this solution from [mkozicki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/677420/mkozicki) which is great as it is not affected by localisation issues (some other methods rely on the value of the button, which may change due to localisation). [How do you handle multiple submit buttons in ASP.NET MVC Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework/7111222#7111222)

**EDIT:** If I am displaying data in a table and just want to know which line I have chosen, I will often create an HTML form for each line. In other words have the `Ajax.BeginForm` *inside* the `foreach` block, then each form can contain the ID which is passed to the controller on postback. This works nicely too and is very simple.